# Laravel Carbon class timestamp

Tags: laravel, timestamp, php-carbon

In my laravel project I didn't migrate the table with timestamp(created_at). I used to get the time with a date column.

I need to filter the data from that table so that I used Laravel Carbon class.

This is my function for filter the data

```
public function getWeeklyData()
    {
        $data = \Carbon\Carbon::today()->subDays(7);

        $weeklydata=DB::table('response')->where('date','>=',$data)
        ->get();

        return view('admin.pages.tables.weeklydata',['weeklydata' => $weeklydata]);
       
    }
```

But there is no output.

Some times my date format is different from Carbon class date format.

If any solution for this?

Comment: `$data = App\Response::where('date', '>=', date('Y-m-d', strtotime(now()->subDays(7))))->get();` try this code

Comment: The easiesy way to change date format with Carbon `$date = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", "2018-05-06");`

Comment: whats your format of this `date` in response table

Comment: Time zone is India Standard Time

Comment: Is the `date` column of the `response` table is DATETIME? Or something else? Make sure the type is correct.

Comment: yea that is DATETIME

Comment: Have you tried `->whereDate('date','>=',$data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use **Carbon** it will carbon object return. so try below

```
$data = \Carbon\Carbon::today()->subDays(7)->format('Y-m-h');

$weeklydata=DB::table('response')->where('date','>=',$data)
        ->get();
```

and you can use **whereDate** also

```
$data = \Carbon\Carbon::today()->subDays(7);
$weeklydata=DB::table('response')->whereDate('date','>=',$data)
            ->get();
```

Comment: I already tried first one but it was render only this year data. I didn't get last 7 days data

Comment: `subDays()` means you subtract 7 days so u wont get it ne ?

Comment: I think my date column format is the issue for that or

Comment: your table column should be `date` or `datetime`

Comment: The data type is VARCHAR. It creates that issue?